# Truffle migrate command ReferenceError: Migrations not defined?

Tags: command, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle

I'm trying to migrate a test smart contract and when I type the command I'm getting a "ReferenceError: Migrations is not defined" NOTE: The error is for my second file, the first one is migrated without any problem. Here's a screenshot of the full error message:

[image: CMD ERROR]

Files in use:

[image: files]

I'll leave the code of each file below:

Ethswap.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract EthSwap {
  string public name = "EthSwap Instant Exchange";
}
```

2_deploy_contracts.js:

```
const EthSwap = artifacts.require("EthSwap");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

1_initial_migration.js:

```
const Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

I'd deeply appreciate a solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `2_deploy_contract.js`, `Migration` is not declared.

Instead of

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

Change it to

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(EthSwap);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error "**ReferenceError: deployer is not defined**".

It turns out I had a spelling mistake in my code. The spelling of "deployer" at function(deployer) was wrong. After the correction every thing worked out.

Comment: doesn't answer the question